# How to generate class diagram using Visual Studio on Mac?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio

I see it's possible with VS for Windows - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/designing-and-viewing-classes-and-types?view=vs-2022

But how do I generate some sort of class/UML diagram using VS for Mac? Any extensions? Or something outside of VS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The class designer tool for mac is still under review.

Vote on the thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/class-designer-2/813567

Comment: @Lewis I am afraid it is not supported. [Visual Studio for Mac is scheduled for retirement on August 31, 2024](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/update?view=vsmac-2022)